# VB.NET: DataGridView different button in same Column

Tags: vb.net

I am tring to initialize a checker that checks the cells of a certain column in datagridview, if the cell is equal to `StaffMixname` then the button text should be `VIEW` if not then the button text is `LOCKED`

here is my code so far.

```
Dim dgButtonColumn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
Dim i As Integer
MetroGrid7.Columns.Add(dgButtonColumn)
dgButtonColumn.HeaderText = "Security"
dgButtonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
For i = 0 To MetroGrid7.Rows.Count
    If MetroGrid7.Rows(i).Cells.Item(4).Value.ToString() = StaffMixname.Text Then
       dgButtonColumn.Text = "VIEW"
       dgButtonColumn.Name = "viewBtn"
       dgButtonColumn.ToolTipText = "View"
    Else
       dgButtonColumn.Text = "LOCKED"
       dgButtonColumn.Name = "searchSecurityBtn"
       dgButtonColumn.ToolTipText = "LOCKED"
    End If
Next
```

[image]

My desired result is like this 
[image]

Comment: If you want different text on each button then the very first thing to do is get rid of this: `dgButtonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True`. You need to set the `Value` for each individual cell just like you would for any other column.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like this. In `DataGridViewButtonColumn` each cell contains a `button` but you can **not** access it. You can get the `DataGridViewButtonCell` and change these two properties `value and ToolTipText`. There is no `name` property in `DataGridViewButtonCell`. So to change them:

```
Dim dgButtonColumn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
Dim i As Integer
MetroGrid7.Columns.Add(dgButtonColumn)
dgButtonColumn.HeaderText = "Security"
'remove this line
'dgButtonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
For i = 0 To MetroGrid7.Rows.Count
    If MetroGrid7.Rows(i).Cells.Item(4).Value.ToString() = StaffMixname.Text Then
       MetroGrid7.Rows(i).Cells.Item(6).Value = "VIEW"
       MetroGrid7.Rows(i).Cells.Item(6).ToolTipText = "View"
    Else
       MetroGrid7.Rows(i).Cells.Item(6).Value = "LOCKED"
       MetroGrid7.Rows(i).Cells.Item(6).ToolTipText = "LOCKED"
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim status As String
status = status & Me.dgTitleList.CurrentRow.Cells("BDO").Value
status = status & Chr(13)
```

Insert the `Value` of the `Datagridview` `Column` to `String` and do the condition.

```
If status = StaffMixname.Text Then
dgButtonColumn.Text = "VIEW"
   dgButtonColumn.Name = "viewBtn"
   dgButtonColumn.ToolTipText = "View"
Else
   dgButtonColumn.Text = "LOCKED"
   dgButtonColumn.Name = "searchSecurityBtn"
   dgButtonColumn.ToolTipText = "LOCKED"
End If
```

And I suggest is to use BreakPoint and check if the `StaffMixName.Text` has a `Value`.

Comment: made it work but, the result reversed from all `LOCKED` to `VIEW`

Comment: Check the value of `StaffMixName.Text`.

Comment: StaffMixname have a value

Comment: Then what it is?

Comment: JOOlive, so the button text should be VIEW

Comment: hi I updated my question and added a picture to show my desired result

Comment: It is a Static or Dynamic `Value`?

Comment: it is dynamic, it depends on who is the user

Comment: So it's just like getting the username of the user? Can i see your code of getting the user and equal to `StaffMixName.Text`.

Comment: simply fetching the data in database using sql functions

Comment: I dont have a problem with the `StaffMixname` my problem is changing the text of the button to `VIEW` if the value of the cell in column `BDO` matches with the value of `StaffMixName` whici is for example `JOOlive`